# Is possible to access an array from another array without a key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array that has another array inside.
[image: student_list array]

Is it possible to access the array[JNI] within the student_list[] array. I have tried the following:

```
student_list[][JNI]
```

It does not work.

How can I access the JNI array?

Comment: `.JNI` - but better to refactor the code that generates that, arrays should not have arbitrary key-value pairs on them

Comment: like this student_list[].JNI?